# Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver not fitering

Tags: .net, foxpro, dbase

Hello i have a strange issue.
I am trying to filter a .dbf file and it seems i just can't.
Whenever i try to apply some kind of Criteria it bombs out..
For example :

```
oCmd.CommandText = "select VAL([CD]),* from Y:\MYFILE.dat WHERE VAL([CD])>800;"
Dim reader = oCmd.ExecuteReader()
reader.Read()
reader.GetString(15)
```

i get a nice : 
System.InvalidOperationException: 'No data exists for the row/column.'
If i query the file without filtering it works just fine...any ideas.
Please do not recommend any other driver..they are just no working in my case due to Greek Encoding..only this driver and after Encoding Conversion provides data instead of gibberish : -λ╕λ?╕▀ ?-▀ⁿ▀

Comment: Since it's a reader, maybe leave out the filter in the select command and filter it on the .NET side.

Comment: I am doing that at the moment but because i need it to be as fast a possible i hoped the driver would do it for me.

Comment: Why is the file extension .DAT? When you say it is fine without the filter, do you mean if you change your CommandText to remove the WHERE then it works OK?

Comment: Yes you are correct....if i remove filtering everything is fine...also .dat is the same as .dbf...in my case

Comment: What driver is it? Also it will only be faster via the driver if there is an index on VAL(CD).

Comment: No index..the CD is numeric..kind..like 001,002

Comment: Any chance it's due to the syntax? In VFP square brackets are a string literal, that is, `"abc" == [abc]` returns true. And, `Val("CD") = 0` thus resulting in 0 records. Can you try removing the square brackets from the where clause (and likely the select too assuming you'd like to get back the data :)?

Comment: I will try that 1st chance i get..although i think i have tried a number of ways

Comment: Well i gave it a go..it seems that "dbase" driver could use "WHERE" to provide some filtering but "needs" the index file...while "FoxPro driver" has no support at all...Anyway i think its a brick wall but given the fact that i need 5 sec for around 70000 rows i guess is not that bad..

Answer (score 0):

if the "CD" column is numeric, you dont need the VAL() function, -- unless it is a string representing all numbers.  If truly a numeric field, you should just be able to do where [CD] > 800.

Also, to help prevent ambiguity of command vs column name (CD change directory) vs the column name CD.  You might want to use aliasing for your table and update your query something like

```
oCmd.CommandText = 
@"select 
         VAL(mf.CD),
         mf.* 
      from 
         MYFILE.dat mf
      WHERE 
         VAL(mf.CD) > 800";
```

if the "CD" column really is numeric, you don't need the VAL() function call

```
oCmd.CommandText = 
@"select 
         mf.* 
      from 
         MYFILE.dat mf
      WHERE 
         mf.CD > 800";
```

Final point.  Your OleDb connection string points to the path (or database) where your files are, so you should not need the explicit full Y:\ path reference to your file name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but finally i implement binary reading with .dbf/.dat which is fast and reliable...i also implemented a mechanism for quickly skipping to records so overall i had to drop the "driver" solution...maybe i will test it some time later...